# How to copy objects behaviors into another from the same type?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, macos, ipad

Is there any opportunity to copy objects behaviors to another?

e.g. I have an label "labelx" with the settings font size = 12 and color = blue
Now I want to pass this settings to another label "y".

Thanks in advance!

Comment: this is not behaviour.

Comment: do you want to do that in IB or in code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
label2.font = label1.font;
label2.textColor = label1.textColor;
```

If you have a lot of this labels it would make sense to add them to 
an array and "copy" the properties in an enumerated loop.

You might want to take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8713488/653513) - it shows a way of 
deep-copying a label.

Comment: The same idea i had before, but istn't there any possibility to do this in one step ?

Comment: Compiler doesn't know which properties you want to copy. I added a link that might interest you.

Comment: You can create custom label in singleton and it will be in one step.

Comment: Great! Exactly what I've searched for. Thanks :)