# Same UILabel in two spots

Tags: ios, uilabel

I have a `UILabel` object instance declared in the interface builder and I set its position with instance method `setFrame:CGRectMake`.

Is it possible to duplicate this label and have it be at two spots on the same view controller?

So have something like this?:

```
[label setFrame:CGRectMake(20,49,135,35)];
[label setFrame:CGRectMake(110,49,135,35)];
```

Because I want to reuse this same label.

Comment: override drawRect, gate a recursive call. I'm not sure on this.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can create a copy of it, check out this answer for how to do that:

[How do copy for UILabel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8712866/how-do-copy-for-uilabel)

Answer (score 0):

In short. No. You have to make a separate `UILabel` object instance.

Tip: create a `UILabel` subclass if you want to provide a custom functionality for your labels and encapsulate that features in a custom class to keep your code clean and well organised.