# How to prevent UILabel's height from shrinking when text field is nil or empty

Tags: ios, interface-builder

I have a `UIView` whose height is constrained to the height of one of it's `UILabels`. However, when the `UILabel` is empty or nil, its height shrinks to nothing and therefore the `UIView's` does as well.

The default height of the `UILabel` with text in it is exactly the height I want my `UIView` to always be, so what is the default height of a `UILabel` or how can I prevent a `UILabel` from shrinking when it's empty?

Comment: add greater than equal to height constraint

Comment: @PatelJigar didn't work

Comment: just give fix height to Label , and the height should be equals to the height of your uiview ....  this will fix your label at a specific height

Comment: @NaveedKhan i would do that, but i don't know what the default height for a `UILabel` is. that's the question

Comment: what if font size of the label

Comment: Just add a height property to label and assign the same height property to UIview

Comment: @NaveedKhan font size of label is 17

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135253/discussion-between-naveed-khan-and-the-beest).

Comment: FYI: I answered this question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33382984/uilabel-text-property-when-set-to-nil-or-makes-uilabel-disappear-from-view-s/48543115#48543115).